# compass in Google Maps stopped working (Xperia V CM 12.1)

Tags: cyanogenmod, google-maps, orientation, compass, sony-xperia-v

In the Google Maps app the compass of my Xperia V (model identifier: LT25i | codename: Tsubasa) doesn't work properly anymore (only 180 degree flips).

To be more precise the compass already stopped working in Google Maps a while ago when I still was on CyanogenMod 11 M12. At the beginning everything was fine then it suddenly stopped working (I assume due to some update of the Google Maps app... unfortunately I can't tell any exact version number).

I hoped it would work again after updating to Android Lollipop ([custom ROM based on CyanogenMod 12.1](http://forum.xda-developers.com/xperia-t-v/v-development/rom-cyanogenmod-12-neo-s-homebuilds-t2967819)) but it didn't (even after a complete wipe and reinstalling).

I guess the problem is not due to a hardware failure because I tested it with two different Xperia V phones and the problem occurs with both of them.

In other apps the compass works as it should (OsmAnd, GPS Status & Toolbox) but in Google Maps it only makes 180 degree flips which makes orientation very difficult. I've found a lot of similar complaints on the net regarding other phone models (as early as 2011) like [this one](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/maps/wafdkjXszxc) but couldn't find any useful information regarding my case.

Does anyone experience the same problem? And more importantly, does anyone know a workaround or something?